# jQuery and pseudo-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

I tried to dynamically change the position of an element which is defined in CSS with `:after`. 
Using this:

```
$(function(){
    $('div::after').css({'top':'20px'})
})
```

But it doesn't work. Are there any ways to change the position?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't. Content created by `:after` or `:before` is not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected or modified.

If you have a look at this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esBrF/1/) and inspect the DOM in Firebug or similar you will see that the pseudo-element is not present in the DOM tree.

A potential solution would be to apply a class to the element you want to change, and to style that class appropriately in CSS:

```
$("div").addClass("newClass");
```

See [this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/esBrF/2/).

Answer (score 2):

add CSS:

```
p.special:before {
    content: "bar";
    position: absolute;
    top : 10px;
}
```

assuming the style sheet where the code above was put is the first one on the page, use this to change it:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('p.special:before','top: 15px;');
```