# jQuery and hiding :after / :before pseudo classes

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery and pseudo-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-classes)

I tried hiding the :after pseudo class via jQuery in a number of ways but with no success, I've found another solution by adding a sort of empty div under my div that contains the :after content and then hiding the div entirely so it gives the same effect.

However I was just curious if anyone had managed to find a way to hide the :after or :before stuff. Here is what I tried that didn't work.

```
$('.search_box:after').hide();
$('.search_box:after').css('display', 'none');
```

Just to give you the context, I have a div that contains the search form etc, and when the search is active I want to enable a little arrow indicator under the div pointing like to the list of found items (built with :after via CSS) and when nothing is found, or it defaults to the full out list (since nothing was found) then I want to hide it.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-classes

Comment: In the end I just used a div right under my search box, with a height of 0 and same width as search box, and it has the after styling and I hide/unhide it instead of the search box, but TJ VanToll's solution below works also well.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Your best bet is to use a class on the element to toggle the display of the pseudo element.

```
<style>
    .search_box:after {
        content: 'foo';
    }
    .search_box.hidden:after {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    //Instead of these 2 lines
    //$('.search_box:after').hide();
    //$('.search_box:after').css('display', 'none');

    //Use
    $('.search_box').addClass('hidden');
</script>
```

**Live example** - http://jsfiddle.net/4nbnh/

Comment: this is the best choice as with other methods you can change the content and color but you cannot change visibility.

Comment: Thanks for answer, This one is best solution i found on internet...

Answer (score 7):

You can dynamically add a `<style>` block to override it. Give it an `id` and you can remove it when needed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/TRLY2/

Script:

```js
$( '#hello' ).click( function () {

    if( $( '#pseudo' ).length ) {
        $( '#pseudo' ).remove();
    } else {
        var css = '<style id="pseudo">#hello::after{display: none !important;}</style>';
        document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', css );
    };

} );
```

​HTML:

```html
<div id="hello">hello</div>​
```

CSS:

```css
#hello::after {
    content: "goodbye";        
}​
```

Answer (score 4):

ThinkingStiff has a pretty good idea.

You could also add and remove a class to for your search box, and only use the after tag with that.

Something like `.hide:after { display:none }` and `.show:after { /* normal css */ }`. Then just swap these classes with javascript.

edit: mixed up the names