# Using jQuery to show/hide an :after pseudo class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div, visitors-main-panel, that shows search results. I have a set of filters above. I would like to show a semi transparent panel over the top of the search results whilst I am fetching the new results via ajax.

```js
$('#visitors-main-panel:after').hide();
```

```css
.visitors-main-panel {
  position: relative;
}
.visitors-main-panel:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-9 visitors-main-panel">
  Initial search results
</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you cannot, pseudo element are not part of the dom and not accessible via jQuery, as advised, toggle a class on the container itself and let CSS take care of itself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. What you should do instead is toggle a class on `#visitors-main-panel` that you use in CSS to target `display` of the pseudo elements.

Comment: It's good to mention your source actually, using google isn't the way to answer questions here m8 :D 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354270/jquery-and-hiding-after-before-pseudo-classes

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant where did you see google in this answer ? This answer points at a good practice, mayb needed a bit more explanation to be ressourcefull for the OP

Comment: Let's not debate please, you just copy-pasted an answer from my quoted link exactly as answered by @TJ Vanholl on Jul 6 '12 at 0:32. And I did not even vote your answer down so ;) ps> Google `jquery hide :after`, hit first link, copy-paste accepted answer.. that was your used technique.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant let's not debate please? You mean you don't like being called out on your bs - you'll do the one-sided bs calling out? "you just copy-pasted an answer from my quoted link exactly as answered by TJ Vanholl on Jul 6 '12 at 0:32" - first, GCyrillus replied to you, not me. And second, I did not copy and paste an answer. That answer and mine are very similar, but not the same, and it's a simple concept - maybe there's a reason our answers are similar, yet not the same. "that was your used technique" don't be so presumptuous, m8 ;)

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant so did I to make my comment under the question. It is a redundant question and there is not other appropriate to give. Instead going for 'this is a copy/paste, propose to close the question for a duplicate of any of the hundreds similar questions standing here for the last few years ... keep cool , it is only a forum where people help each others :)

Comment: I appreciate the help from you all ;-)

Comment: Chiming in as well -- SO should be a helpful place, while it is good to call out others if they're really copy/pasting a previous answer vs linking to relevant questions in the past, this is a fairly straightforward issue with straightforward answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.uk-hidden { display: none; }
</style>

$('.visitors-main-panel:after').addClass('uk-hidden');
```

ps> Your CSS selector has quote as an opening and one double-quote as a closure, make sure you use either quotes or double quotes.

ps2> Your CSS defines a class, where your jQuery selector is trying to access an element by it's ID.

Comment: you should setup a snippet or a fiddle to demonstrate it works ;)

Comment: Thank you - I think I may have misunderstood something - I've made a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/v5dfc6h6/

Comment: Got it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-elements was very helpful. Thank you.