# How to animate or timing a Pseudo class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, pseudo-class

Say I have an element and I want to change it on a hover state.

Using a `Pseudo` class it will look like this:

```
#element:before { background-position: 0px -50px; }
#element:hover:before { background-position: -50px -50px; }
```

Can I implement a jQuery `animation` function to it? or can I time its transition?

Comment: Did you try $("#element:before").animate()?

Comment: Isn't using a PURE CSS solution is better?

Comment: Of course it can be solved by CSS only, however I'm loosing the ability and advantages of using a Pseudo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with jQuery.

> Content created by :after or :before is not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected or modified.
>   - *([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969048/1344955))*

You could use this in your CSS to achive a transition effect, but this will not work in older browsers:

```
#element:before {
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-position 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-position 1s linear;
    transition: background-position 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Regarding the Pseudo class, that was informative. I'll use a CSS transition :(

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `.prev()`?

```
$(".block").prev().animate();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/EkW4z/

Comment: In your example, it uses classes to reposition an element which can be also a solution however, it's important to know, as @DJDavid98 wrote, that before and after are NOT part of the DOM and therefor can't be modified.

Comment: @Lior Not exactly. You do not need to use classes on the elements, I only used them to style it.

Comment: it uses the animation() function and working fine BUT without manipulating on a Pseudo class. The prev() function used for tracking the preceding sibling of each of its elements but not more than that. Anyway, thanks a lot for putting your time in to it.