# Pseudo element :before and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a element which has two borders. I achieved that by adding a pseudo element:

```
.inner:before {
    width: 72px;
    height: 28px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
}
```

The element is wrapped with another div which has the property `overflow: hidden`.

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HKEn4/1/ the .inner-element is hidden but not the pseudo element (tested with safari, firefox and chrome on OSX).

How can I hide the pseudo element?

Comment: See [jQuery and pseudo-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-elements)

Comment: What's the absolute positioning on the pseudo element good for?

Comment: @CBroe It certainly helped create the overflow problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I added `position: relative;` in the `.wrapper` class and it works!

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HKEn4/2/

Comment: Note: if `.inner` contains ANY `transform`, the pseudo-element will get clipped. [Demo](https://codepen.io/floatingrock/pen/dyMoRMr)

Answer (score 4):

Either remove the `position:absolute` from the `:before` pseudo-element, or add `position:relative` to the container..