# bootstrap 3 responsive multiple mega menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, megamenu

I work with bootstrap 3 and design mega menu navigation.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaMenu</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                        <div class="item"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                        <div class="item"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.carousel -->
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                                <form class="form" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection 2<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                        <div class="item"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                        <div class="item"> <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>

                                             <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button>
                                            <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Item -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.carousel -->
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                                <form class="form" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                </form>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown {
    position: static !important;
    width:100%;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 285px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #999;
    white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover, .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    color: #428bca;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu form {
    margin:3px 20px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Now, i ahve two `<ul>` for navigation menu . in both i see one `sub menu`. me mean is  if i click in collection Or collection 2 i see one sub menu.

how do can i fix this ?

**Problem** : `click on collection and collection 2 u see one submenu bottom of collection not for collection 2.`

[image]

> Note: The Position of the arrow is to be changed. For both the dropdowns, the upward arrows indicate the same position. This position is to be changed like

1. First Dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlWPN.png
2. Second Dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrP9D.png

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P56Cr/1/)

Comment: Good for fiddle. What do u want to fix??

Comment: @user3168736: click on collection and collection 1 u see one submenu bottom of collection not for collection 1.

Comment: @Devang웃 I think, the last picture says it all. Also the text above that picture, maybe it is not really clear, but I get it.

Comment: Yes, for the same, I have tried to edit the question, I hope this clearly defines the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue occurs because the css triangle is being positioned relative to overall `navbar`.  As this element's position does not change, the triangle does to reposition itself.

The ideal solution is to embed the triangle within the currently selected item.  To achieve this remove

```
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

and replace with

```
.open .dropdown-toggle:after {
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    left: 163px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -21px;
    z-index: 1500;
}
.open .dropdown-toggle span:after {
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -41px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

This attaches the triangle to the text and down arrows, and positions it relative to these elements.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7eHFd/4/

Update: In the above the triangle remains in place when sizing down.  To workaround this, wrap with above code with a media query.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7eHFd/5/

Comment: Hi, Can i use this on Bootstrap 4 ?

Comment: @anunixercoder : Not sure, I have not tried this with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** [JS Fiddle Solution Link](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/ygP3G/)

> Information:

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-elements) link, you can't adjust psudo class css. Styling or Content created by :after or :before is not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected or modified.

Also, this solution is suitable for:

1. Responsive Design
2. The menu arrow, will be positioned to the center of the menu item.[image: Arrow Position]

**Issues:**

> Psudo class CSS:

```
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 285px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 283px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

So, for the same, `.mega-dropdown-menu' class need to be reset the psudo border styling.

**Solution:** [JS Fiddle Solution Link](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/ygP3G/)

And so, a new element is to be added for which has the same styling as under:

> CSS changes:

```
.show{
    display: block;
}
.arrow1, .arrow2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
}
.open .arrow1, .open .arrow2 {
    display: block;
}
.arrow1 span:after, .arrow2 span:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 2px;
}
.arrow1 span:before, .arrow2 span:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after, .mega-dropdown-menu:before{border: none;}
```

> JS Changes:

```
$(".nav > li.mega-dropdown").eq( 0 ).append("<p class='arrow1 arrOw'><span></span></p>");
$(".nav > li.mega-dropdown").eq( 1 ).append("<p class='arrow2 arrOw'><span></span></p>");

$(".nav > li.mega-dropdown").eq( 0 ).click(function () {
    //x = $(".mega-dropdown.open").position();
    x = $(this).position();
    aa = x.left+75;
    $(this).find(".arrow1").css("left", aa);
});
$(".nav > li.mega-dropdown").eq( 1 ).click(function () {
    //x = $(".mega-dropdown.open").position();
    x = $(this).position();
    aa = x.left + 75;
    $(this).find(".arrow2").css("left", aa);
});
```

If you have any other issue, then please add a comment below.

Regards D.

Answer (score 1):

> One Issue Solved here >> [**Mega drop down triangle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/LLV6W/4/)

[FullScreen View](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/LLV6W/4/embedded/result/)

checked on 1920 X 1080 Resolution! Its Working!
[image]

Working on Second!

> css

```
  body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown {
    position: static !important;
    width:100%;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu-1:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu-1:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu-2:before {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu-2:after {
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 19px solid transparent;
    border-left: 19px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #999;
    white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover, .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    color: #428bca;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu form {
    margin:3px 20px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Please Check it once again [LINK](http://imgur.com/CyBcLb5)....it is not responsive!!! Bootstrap is used, so it should be responsive. Regards.