# Bootstrap:don't know how to make a stylish mega menu

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to make mega-menu [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8N1ceoVucXAQS0zVkFuWFFUeGc/view?usp=sharing). From the document of bootstrap, i still can't make this stylish mega-menu. I am using bootstrap ver 3.2.0.
I am looking for a guide step by step. But i don't see any of them.
Please help me.
With all my heart, thank a lot.

p/s: i am newbie with front-end, was back-end member 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer above this link. I think help you!

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu

https://github.com/geedmo/yamm3

[bootstrap 3 responsive multiple mega menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057451/bootstrap-3-responsive-multiple-mega-menu)

Comment: Thank for your useful guide.

Comment: Very happy help you!. Xin chân thành cảm ơn!