# how to add / Remove :after class to div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How to can we add/Remove :after class to div using jQuery

let say I have following class

```
.vignetteC1:after { ... }
.vignetteC2:after { ... }
.vignetteC3:after { ... }
.vignetteC4:after { ... }
.vignetteC5:after { ... }
```

if we want to add after class to a dive using jQuery how can we do so. ?

I have googled a lot but I am only getting an example of .after function and so on.

I have tried the following but it not working

```
var VignetteVal = 'vignetteC' + value + ':after';

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  Img.parent().removeClass(('vignetteC' + i + ':after'));
}

Img.parent().addClass(VignetteVal);
```

But the above code add vignetteC2: after class to div 
like

```
<div class="vignetteC2: after">
```

Comment: `.vignetteC1` is a class, whereas `.vignetteC1:after` is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968992/jquery-and-pseudo-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add pseudo classes to elements using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: I would pre-define `pseudo-elements` with particular class selectors in the CSS, then just toggle/add/remove the classes as required, so if I no longer require `.vignetteC5:after` I would rather remove the class `.vignetteC5`. To preserve the naming convention of your selectors it may be better to assign those `pseudo-elements` to classes like "`.pseudoEl`", then declare your properties like: `.vignetteC1.psuedoEl:after`, `.vignetteC2.psuedoEl:after`, `.vignetteC3.psuedoEl:after`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are very confused about what `:after` is. It's a pseudo-element. It is NOT a class and not part of the DOM structure so it cannot be edited or added with javascript.

Read more here > https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

`:after` pseudo-element adds content after the content of an element. It is not a class. To add content after an element you can use `insertAfter()` or you can use `append` to add content at the end of the current element. Also, there is an `after()` method

- [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)
- [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)